# Using @extend directives with classes and placeholder selectors?

Tags: css, sass

My main concern is more focused towards a best practice, and to know when should I use `@extend` directives with **classes** and when with **placeholder selectors**? Since they both do virtually the same.

I've read a few articles where the authors would create a certain class to use them only with `@extend` directives. Wouldn't placeholder selectors make the compiling process more performant?

I'm thinking that maybe `@extend` directives should be used with classes if that class is being used by another element, otherwise these directives should be used with placeholder selectors; but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define placeholder selector, it won't be compiled into css - it will only happen if you extend it. With class selector, it will always be compiled, regardless of whether or not you extend it. Therefore less code = more performance :)

From [SASS Documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholders)

> Sometimes you’ll write styles for a class that you only ever want to @extend, and never want to use directly in your HTML. This is especially true when writing a Sass library, where you may provide styles for users to @extend if they need and ignore if they don’t.
>
> If you use normal classes for this, you end up creating a lot of extra CSS when the stylesheets are generated, and run the risk of colliding with other classes that are being used in the HTML. That’s why Sass supports “placeholder selectors” (for example, %foo).